# "I did it!" - is there better translation?

Tags: перевод, выражения

In [modern] Russian media literal translation

> "Я сделал(а) это!"

is being commonly used. Is there better way to translate this expression? Or is there equivalent expression that can be used that would convey similar meaning?

Comment: Мне кажется, в русском языке вместо неопределённого "Я сделал(а) это!" чаще описывают конкретное действие: "Я поступил(а)!", "Я прыгнул(а) с парашютом!" и т.д.

Comment: I meant uses of literal translation as discussed here: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36435/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%AF-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE but was hoping to find better russian expression to describe same sentiment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ask about the best *translation* which is hard to say without a context.

*Я сделал это* really exists in the last years as a calque from English. Should it be used or not - it really depends. Though I'm sure that at least on some occasions one could (and should) change it to something more common, like *Получилось*, *Готово*, *Сделано*, *Есть!* etc.

Having said this, I don't think that *Я сделал это* should be absolutely inadmissible. After all, people do say like this.

Comment: Thank you! There is no special context really. The question was just a reaction on Russian news program where journalist exclaimed "Я сделал это!" and it just sounded so wrong.

Comment: @InitK Well, we're used to expect of "better language usage" in news programs. _Я сделал это_ by any means is a _colloquial_ expression, which doesn't fit a formal conversation.

Answer (score 6):

Use an impersonate construction like *получилось!*, *удалось!*, *у меня вышло!* and similar.

Comment: I guess "Ура!" or "Дело сделано!" can be used as well.

Comment: @InitK: sure, they might as well be.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase sounds very stupid. I would replace it with

> У меня получилось

Comment: У меня получилось sounds just as silly imo XD
In the context of what we what it to mean here.